# MODX Revo pdoPage выводит повторы

Tags: pdo, modx, revo

Вывожу позиции таким кодом:

```
 <div id="pdopage">
            [[!+page.nav]]
            <div class="rows">
[[!pdoPage?
  &parents=`0`
  &ajaxMode=`scroll`
  &limit=`6`
  &wrapIfEmpty=`Ничего не найдено`
  &tpl=`items.row`
  &includeTVs=`about,status,basic,more,index`
  &where=`["(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(index) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )", [[!filter]]]`
  &sortby=`{"sort30":"DESC"}`
  &showLog=`0`
  ]]
```

По мере прокрутки подгружает по 6 штук, вроде всё нормально. Но в какой-то момент обнаруживаю, что один из элементов уже есть на странице и выведен повторно. В моём случае это критично и повторов быть не должно.
Может ли быть причиной, что в базе столбец sort30 меняется извне ежеминутно для обеспечения рандомной сортировки результатов? Как бороться?

Да, отключил изменение sort30, повторы пропали. Тогда другой вопрос: как добиться рандомной сортировки?

Поставил &sortby=`RAND()`, так вообще по 4 раза начали выходить.

Comment: Посмотрите  с &showLog=`1` (с &sortby=RAND()), чтго в логах пишет, случайно список ресурсов не меняется из-за where? у меня такой вызов прекрасно работает, выводит в случайном порядке

Comment: Вопрос решен в продолжении темы [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908959/modx-revo-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-pdopage)