# MODX Revo вставить плейсхолдер в pdoPage

Tags: modx, revo

В продолжение темы [pdoPage выводит повторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907997/280456).
Пытаюсь сначала сохранить всю выборку в плейсхолдер

```
[[!pdoResources?
  &parents=`0`
  &includeTVs=`about,status,basic,more,index`
  &where=`["UNIX_TIMESTAMP(index) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()"]`
  &sortby=`RAND()`
  &toPlaceholder=`sortedList`
  ]]
```

а потом выводить в pdoPage

```
[[!pdoPage?
  &parents=`0`
  &ajaxMode=`scroll`
  &tpl=`items.row`
  &resources=`[[+sortedList]]`
  ]]
```

И не работает. Я что-то не так делаю или так не получится?

Добавил через 3 часа:

Проверил содержание плейсхолдера так: [Вывести все доступные плейсхолдеры](https://webstool.ru/printplaceholders.html)
В наличии имеем:

```
[sortedList] => 

Array
(
[id] => 492
[type] => document
[contentType] => text/html
// тут еще штук 30 строк
[tv.about] => текст о компании
[tv.basic] => 106
[tv.more] => 112
)    
Array
(
[id] => 431
// аналогично с первым массивом
)
Array
(
[id] => 511
// аналогично с первым массивом
)
Array // и так далее...
```

Получается, плейсхолдер сортируется и пишется нормально.

Comment: Во втором запросе вы должны получить `&resources` - список ресурсов, через запятую, для вывода в результатах. Значит в первом запросе вы должны получить этот список: `&returnIds`  Установите значение «1», чтобы вернуть строку со списком id ресурсов, вместо оформленных результатов. Все указанные шаблоны игнорируются.

Comment: Tunker, простите, я ничего не понял из Вашего комментария.
"Во втором запросе вы должны получить &resources - список ресурсов, через запятую" - так что туда написать? Вопрос дополнил, может что-то прояснит

Comment: Мои первые шаги в MODX. Сильно не ругайтесь.

Comment: В первом чанке вы должны прописать `&returnIds=` ` `1` `

Comment: Я это пробовал, тогда вообще плейсхолдер не пишется

Comment: странно, т.е. вы в первом чанке pdoResources, пишете &returnIds=1 а [sortedList] не принимает значение типа 492,431,511?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сначала должны получить список ресурсов

```
[[!pdoResources?
  &parents=`0`
  &includeTVs=`about,status,basic,more,index`
  &where=`["UNIX_TIMESTAMP(index) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()"]`
  &sortby=`RAND()`
  &toPlaceholder=`sortedList`
  &returnIds=`1`
  ]]
```

При этом чанк `[[+sortedList]]` примет вид: 492,511, и т.д. т.е. только список ресурсов. Далее его подставлять в вызов pdoPage

```
[[!pdoPage?
  &parents=`0`
  &ajaxMode=`scroll`
  &tpl=`items.row`
  &resources=`[[+sortedList]]`
 ]]
```

Comment: А так теряется рандомная сортировка. Выходят все строго по списку. Убрал &tpl=`items.row` дабы посмотреть готовую строку, да, по возрастанию идет порядок.

Comment: А если &sortby=`RAND()` поставить в вызов pdoPage?  ведь по сути в первом вызове вы получаете только список ресурсов которые надо вывести, а вот выводите их (и соответственно сортируете) во втором вызове

Comment: И вернёмся к тому, с чего всё началось: pdoPage выводит повторы

Comment: А вы не пробовали посмотреть содержимое чанка `[[+sortedList]]`? может там есть повторы? попробуйте запускатьс параметром `&showLog=` ` `1 ` `

Comment: Конечно смотрел, там всё норм. А вообще история началась отсюда:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907997/280456
Может, я не в том направлении пошёл?

Comment: Tunker, в итоге, получилось, только немног изменил Ваш код. В первом запросе оставил 

&sortby=`{"sort30":"DESC"}`

заполняя поле внешним сниппетом рандомными значениями.
Во втором надо было всего лишь добавить
&sortby=`ids`. Спасибо огромное.